# Couldn't install netbeans 11.3 with Java 14 due to Error: "Unsupported JVM version"

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, netbeans-11, java-14

I'm trying to install netbeans with Java 14.

I'm getting below error -

```
> sudo ./Apache-NetBeans-11.3-bin-linux-x64.sh --javahome /home/raj/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Unsupported JVM version at /home/raj/.sdkman/candidates/java/current.
Try to specify another JVM location using parameter --javahome
```

Below are my java details -

```
> which java
/home/raj/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java


> java --version
openjdk 14 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14+36-1461)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14+36-1461, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My OS Details are -

```
> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: openSUSE
Description:    openSUSE Leap 15.1
Release:        15.1
Codename:       n/a
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although Apache NetBeans 11.3 fully supports the use of JDK 14, unfortunately its installer does not. From the [Apache NetBeans 11.3 download page](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb113/nb113.html):

> **The installers will not run under JDK 14** because usage is made of the
>   Pack200 Tools and API, for packing and unpacking, which is removed in
>   JDK 14, see JEP 367.

See [JEP 367: Remove the Pack200 Tools and API](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/367) for full details on why this change was made in JDK 14.

Your workarounds for this issue are:

- Instead of using the installer, download and unzip the zip of Apache NetBeans 11.3 (named **netbeans-11.3-bin.zip**) [from the download page](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb113/nb113.html). This approach worked for me.
- Install a version of the JDK < 14, and you can then use the installer to install NetBeans 11.3 with that JDK. Once NetBeans 11.3 is installed you could edit **netbeans.conf** to make JDK 14 the default Java platform, or simply add it as a second Java platform using **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...**

Comment: If you use the first workaround, in order to launch the IDE you'll have to find its executable. After you extract the file to the directory of your choice, you'll find the launcher file in ***your_directory\netbeans\bin\***  and click on netbeans.exe or netbeans64.exe.

Comment: I have JDK 11 and when I try to install netbeans via installer Apache-NetBeans-11.3-bin-linux-x64.sh I am not able to pinpoint to the location of JDK. Help pls.

Comment: I guess nothing should be so easy with Java anymore :)