# NetBeans 11 lack of setup installation file

Tags: netbeans

I have downloaded the Netbeans 11 from Apache but unlike versions before the netbeans project goes to Apache foundation there is not installation setup file for Windows. I need to look up to the application folder to find the netbeans.exe. Why?

Comment: [1] The [download page for NetBeans 11.3](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html) states _"**Apache NetBeans 11.0 is available for download from your closest Apache mirror. For this release no official installers are provided**, please just download the binaries and unzip them."_. [2] The reason for that is off topic for SO. Pursue it with the NetBeans Team if you really care because only they can give an authoritative answer. [3] Subsequent releases of NetBeans 11.x do provide installers.

Comment: Thank you... 11.3 version that has installers said that is not working with jdk 14... Mamma mia... why open source is so unnecessarily complicated...

Comment: Correct - the installer for 11.3 won't work with JDK 14. But there are easy workarounds for that - see [Couldn't install netbeans 11.3 with Java 14 due to Error: “Unsupported JVM version”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60922968/2985643). For most it may be preferable to use 11.3 since it contain bug fixes from earlier versions, and allows you to use JDK 14.

Comment: Thank you... Also I found that in 11 intellisence doesn't work... many problems.. so I installed 11.3 with jdk 13 and then edit the used jdk from netbeans to 14. Because I had 13 and 14 version simultaneously Ι had to change the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path of 13

Comment: That all sounds good. One final minor bit of housekeeping is that you could also now edit the NetBeans configuration file **etc/netbeans.conf** to make JDK 14 the default JDK, and then remove JDK 13, but that's completely optional.