# Netbeans 11.3 not installing - java.lang.noClassDefFoundError - pack200

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to install Netbeans 11.3 (IDE) on my new laptop, but every time it gives me this error box [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgEMr.png)

Essentially its telling me that a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError of java/util/jar/Pack200 happened in thread main.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what happened. JDK 14, the latest version, doesn't have a pack200, and Netbeans 11.3 isn't compatible with JDK-14.

Comment: You are right that JDK 14 doesn't include the Pack200 API, but it is completely incorrect to state that "_Netbeans 11.3 isn't compatible with JDK-14_". NetBeans 11.3 fully supports JDK-14. The problem lies with the installer of NetBeans 11.3 when run using JDK-14, and not NetBeans itself. See [Couldn't install netbeans 11.3 with Java 14...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60922968/2985643).

Comment: What's the difference? NetBeans isn't working.

Comment: You are posting incorrect information, and there is a big difference between the installer not working and NetBeans not working. NetBeans works fine with JDK 14. Read the link I provided. It clearly explains what you are not understanding.