# Unable to install c++ on netbeans

Tags: c++, macos, installation, netbeans

After going to the plugins section,

[image]

I proceeded with the regular installation:

[image]
[image]

But after some installation screens, netbeans gave me this error:

[image]

which happened right after this loaded for a while:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Note: I am using macOS Mojave

Edit:
After receiving suggestions to change the JDK netbeans is using, netbeans can't open:
[image]

Comment: The Netbeans Bug Report ["The Plugin Installer found problem timeout of loading C/C++ Remote Development API org.netbeans.modules.cnd.api.remote/1.29.5.1 while install the following plugins: C++](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4452?src=confmacro") is relevant if NetBeans is running under JDK 14. If so, the solution is to reconfigure NetBeans to use a JDK < 14 to install C++. Once that is done you can revert to using JDK14. That tedious workaround is necessary only because [the installer for NB 12 is incompatible with JDK 14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924824/2985643).

Comment: However, if you are already running NetBeans with a JDK < 14 then update your question with the relevant portion of the NetBeans Log (**View > IDE Log**) that was written during the failed installation of the C/C++ plugin.

Comment: Ahh ok I will try that, I am using JDK 14

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved?

Comment: No. In fact now I can't even open netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
sudo cp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/unpack200 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin